# SQLite - update from view

Tags: sql, sqlite, view, sql-update, database-trigger

I have a view:

```
    CREATE VIEW UsersCounts AS SELECT
        users.id,
        users.username,
        users.email,
        SUM(CASE WHEN orders.id > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as orders_all,
        SUM(CASE WHEN orders.status='ACTIVE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as orders_active,
        SUM(CASE WHEN orders.status='RETURNED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as orders_returned
    FROM users
        INNER JOIN orders ON
            users.email = orders.email
    GROUP BY users.id
```

Result:

```
id | username | email | orders_all | orders_active | orders_returned
```

How i can set `Users.customer_status = "VIP"'` where `orders_active > 5`?

Comment: You want to show that in that view? Or do you want to update any table? The title of the question and the description leave room for interpretation...

Answer (score 1):

example:

update table from view id
set age < 18 unable smoke

> ```
> create table TestTable (id int,age int,smokable NVARCHAR(8));
> ```

> ```
> CREATE VIEW TestView AS SELECT
> id,
> case when age < 18 then 'young' 
> else 'old'
> end status
> from TestTable;
> ```

> ```
> insert into TestTable (id,age,smokable) values (1,25,null),(2,17,null),(3,12,null),(4,9,null);
> ```

> ```
> select * from TestView;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | status
> :- | :-----
> 1  | old   
> 2  | young 
> 3  | young 
> 4  | young
> ```

> ```
> select * from TestTable;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | age | smokable
> :- | :-- | :-------
> 1  | 25  | null    
> 2  | 17  | null    
> 3  | 12  | null    
> 4  | 9   | null
> ```

> ```
> update TestTable
> set smokable = 'Unable'
> where id in (select id from TestView where status = 'young');
> ```

> ```
> select * from TestTable;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | age | smokable
> :- | :-- | :-------
> 1  | 25  | null    
> 2  | 17  | Unable  
> 3  | 12  | Unable  
> 4  | 9   | Unable
> ```

Answer (score 0):

For the update  you could use

```
    UPDATE users 
    SET customer_status = 'VIP'
    where EXISTS ( SELECT orders_active
                   FROM orders_active
                   WHERE  users.email = email
                   AND  orders_active > 5
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You would do:

```
CREATE VIEW UsersCounts AS
    SELECT u.id, u.username, u.email,
           SUM(CASE WHEN o.id > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as orders_all,
           SUM(CASE WHEN o.status = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as orders_active,
           SUM(CASE WHEN o.status = 'RETURNED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as orders_returned,
           (CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN o.status = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 5
                 THEN 'VIP'
                 ELSE MAX(u.customer_status)
            END) as customer_status
    FROM users u INNER JOIN
         orders o
         ON u.email = o.email
    GROUP BY u.id
```